# Regular expression to parse the time-stamp string in ActionScript3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am working on a project in ActionScript3. I have this function that parses a time-stamp string.

```
private function convertTimestampToNumber(timestamp:String):Number {
    //YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS:sss
    var re:RegExp = /(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{2})-(?P<day>\d{2})\s(?P<hour>\d{2}):(?P<min>\d{2}):(?P<sec>\d{2})\.(?P<msec>\d{3})/;
    var result:Array = re.exec(timestamp);
    Alert.show(timestamp, "Timestamp string", Alert.OK);

    return (10000000000000 * parseInt(result.year)
        + 100000000000 * parseInt(result.month)
        + 1000000000 * parseInt(result.day)
        + 10000000 * parseInt(result.hour)
        + 100000 * parseInt(result.min)
        + 1000 * parseInt(result.sec)
        + parseInt(result.msec));
}
```

This seems to work fine for all time-stamps except `"2016-08-01 09:19:43.23"`. Here it throws an error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

I thought since the millisecond part of this time-stamp is only 2 chars long, it was throwing error. To fix this I changed the millisecond part of the regular expression to `(?P<msec>\d{2|3})` thinking that now it would consider both 2-character and 3-character long millisecond as valid, but now it throws the same error on `"2015-11-19 15:28:29.737"`.

What will be the correct regular expression that can consider both scenarios as valid?

Comment: What is the result supposed to represent? Isn't `100000 * parseInt(result.min)` a different unit then `parseInt(result.msec))` Is your intention to return all numbers separately at a different decimal place of the Number that you are returning? Can't you just use the Date` class?

Comment: Yes, my intention is to return all numbers separately at a different decimal place of the number that I am returning. Does the `Date` class have a function to do that?

Comment: Any feedback @Sonu Mishra ?

Answer (score 2):

Your change is *almost* right. What you can do is this:

```
(?P<msec>\d{1,3})
```

Which will match any number of milliseconds, from 1 digit (possible, though unlikely to appear) to 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you use de Date Class, you may format your result as you want.

Check and adapt the [DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html) code here bellow
And check for [setDateTimePattern()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html#setDateTimePattern()) method too.:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeStyle;

var currentTime = new Date();
function formatDate(date:Date) {
    var dtf:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("fr-FR");
    // or new DateTimeFormatter("en-EN");
    dtf.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    var longDate:String = dtf.format(date);
    trace(longDate)+getTimer();
    //trace("   *** LocaleID requested=" + dtf.requestedLocaleIDName);
    //trace("   *** Format requested (" + dtf.getDateTimePattern() + ")");
}
trace(" setDateTimePattern example");
formatDate(currentTime);
// output the current time formated as "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
// no Milliseconds avalaible now!
```

Just check the reference, and you'll find an answer AMO.
Hope this helps.